# Qubit relaxation time dependencies

Tags: error-correction

The qubit relaxation time $T_1$ is an important parameter in order to describe the coherence time that a qubit presents, that is, the time in which its coherence quantum state is not compromised by decoherence. Such parameter is important in order to see the needed actuation of a quantum error correction code so that the information can be corrected properly.

Literature often presents this parameter for different qubit technologies as average, max and min times. However, I am wondering if this parameter is dependent to some other parameters such as temperature fluctuations, magnetic fields etc. If so it would be interesting to provide references to research about such effects.